# Using gradle's IDEA plugin for a deeply nested project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

we have a project structure like so:

```
root
    core
        auth
        ...
```

In the root's build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

and its settings.gradle:

```
include 'core'
```

The core has a gradle.build file and a settings.gradle with:

```
include 'auth'
```

So, when I run from the root:

```
gradle idea
```

It'll build the ipr, iws and iml files on the root, and the core folder will have a core.iml. But the auth module does not get created. I have to go into intellij and manually add the module to core. Kind of annoying. Does gradle support deeply nested projects like this, or is this a limitation of the IDEA plugin? Or, quite possibly, I'm doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. I'll phrase this for best google results: A deeply nested gradle project only can have one settings.gradle file at the root, and it looks like this:

```
include 'core'
include 'core:auth'
```

Once this is done, gradle will read in all subprojects and configure IDEA accordingly.